# VBA Copy & pasting adjacent columns of multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, row

I wrote a simple macro to Copy and paste one row of two adjacent columns,I then added the app.ontime to automatically run the copy&paste macro. I have multiple rows of data I want to apply my macro to. Any thoughts?

```
Public Sub PasteDynamicData()

'runs TestKDdata every Xmin

Sheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD").Range("C4").Copy

Range("J4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD").Range("I4:j4").Insert _
shift:=xlDown

Sheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD").Range("D4").Copy

Range("m4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD").Range("L4:M4").Insert _
shift:=xlDown

Sheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD").Range("i87:m87").ClearContents
End Sub

 Public Sub UpdateDataClock()
 'Clock that prompts running of PasteDynamicData
 Sheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD").Select
 Call PasteDynamicData
 Nexttick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
 Application.OnTime Nexttick, "updatedataclock"

        If Time >= TimeValue("16:00:00") Then
        Application.OnTime Nexttick, "updatedataclock", , False
End If
End Sub


(I declared "nexttick as date" in the module).
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what exactly the problem is? What do you want fixed or improved? Is something not working?

Anyway, try the following:

```
Public Sub PasteDynamicData()

Dim xlMovingSheet As Worksheet
Set xlMovingSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MOVINGAVGDATAFromKD")

xlMovingSheet.Range("C4").Copy

xlMovingSheet.Range("J4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

xlMovingSheet.Range("I4:j4").Insert _
shift:=xlDown

xlMovingSheet.Range("D4").Copy

xlMovingSheet.Range("m4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

xlMovingSheet.Range("L4:M4").Insert _
shift:=xlDown

xlMovingSheet.Range("i87:m87").ClearContents

Call UpdateDataClock
End Sub
```

For the update section, set whatever time increment that you'd like. Right now it is set to run PasteDynamicData every 30 seconds.

```
Public Sub UpdateDataClock()

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "PasteDynamicData"

If Time >= TimeValue("16:00:00") Then
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30"), Procedure:="PasteDynamicData", Schedule:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Rwisch45 I am a newbee Vba'r so I wrote the code in steps. When I started writing the code I applied it to only one set of data, & now I am in the last step of my macro; trying to expand the code to apply to a variably sized range of 20+ rows (data points).